# Webdriver is not passing from one method to another

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the code below. Test with priority 1 is executed successfully, but the code written under `@test` with priority 2 is not execution.

Basically, webdriver is passing to another test. If I write all the code under the first test, it is executed successfully.

```
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.TabSelectionHandler;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.asserts.*;



public class NonVodafone_TestNG 
{
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static WebDriverWait wait;

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void AuthorizeURL() throws InterruptedException 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\SinghA28\\Documents\\Abhimanyu_Office_Backup\\Softwares\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();        
        driver.get("https://dev.id.vodafone.com/mockup/");

        //Generating Authorize URL  
        driver.findElement(By.id("env_idp")).sendKeys("PreProd");
        driver.findElement(By.id("opco")).sendKeys("NV");
        driver.findElement(By.id("btn_debug_url")).click();
        driver.get(driver.findElement(By.id("txt_url")).getAttribute("value"));
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("button")).click();
    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void LandingPage()
    {   
        //Assert.assertEquals(true, driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='form']/div[1]/div[1]/label")).isDisplayed());
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: You have defined a static class variable webdriver but then you defined another one in the first test which you are working with. The static variable is undefined which you are trying to use in second test.

Comment: i am getting a nullpointer exception :(

Comment: If you switch the priorities between the 2 tests you will get NPE much sooner.. try it

Comment: yes m getting NPE if i switch the priorities. 
i am new to Selenium webdriver. How can i fix this ?? :(

Comment: This has nothing to do with Selenium, the Java part is not correct. Use driver = new ChromeDriver(); instead of ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();... This will initialize the static class driver variable.

Comment: oh yes .. now i got he problem and solution .. thanks man .. 
and yeah i new to java as well :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At `AuthorizeURL()`, you declare a new variable `ChromeDriver driver` in method's scope. You have to assign it to the class property `WebDriver driver`.

```
@Test(priority=1)
    public void AuthorizeURL() throws InterruptedException 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\SinghA28\\Documents\\Abhimanyu_Office_Backup\\Softwares\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        NonVodafone_TestNG.driver = new ChromeDriver(); // <-- HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

As driver reference variable is already declared you just need to call it.Change the code

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

To

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Hope it will help you :)